# Determinant of skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{2n\times 2n}$, where $a_{i,j} = \ln\left(i-j+\sqrt{\left(i-j\right)^2+1}\right)$ be a skew symmetric matrix of even order $2n$. Then $\det A = ?$

Comment: It's not obvious to me that this matrix is skew symmetric, but I'll assume that's a fact that you have verified.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{a^2+1}} = \frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+1}}{(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})(-a+\sqrt{a^2+1})} = -a+\sqrt{a^2+1}$$. Then $$a_{i,j} = \ln\left(i-j+\sqrt{\left(i-j\right)^2+1}\right) = \ln\left(-(j-i)+\sqrt{\left(j-i\right)^2+1}\right)=\\=\ln\left(\frac{1}{(j-i)+\sqrt{\left(j-i\right)^2+1}}\right) = -a_{j,i}.$$

Comment: Since each matrix element depends only on $i-j$, the matrix is also Toeplitz (constant along diagonals). There's a ton of literature on such determinants.